# IIS: Cannot get spashup preloader to work

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have not yet managed to get a static HTML spashup preloader file to show up before the application is ready to display it's page.

I have googled everything there is to be found on the topic but it is still not working.

We are using IIS 8.5 with Windows Server 2012 R2 (64 bit).

What I have done:

1) "Application Initialization" is enabled under "Server Manager". (I have tried un-installing the "Application Initialization" feature and re-installing it with no luck)

2) "Preloader" is enabled for the site in IIS.

3) I have inserted the following into web.config under system.webServer:

```
        <applicationInitialization remapManagedRequestsTo="preloader.htm" skipManagedModules="true" doAppInitAfterRestart="false">
            <clear />
            <add initializationPage="/" hostName="test.xxxxxxx.com" />
        </applicationInitialization>
```

("test.xxxxxxx.com" instead of our real site and initializationPage is set to "/" just to see if I can get any reaction).

4) We have this simple asp.net script (test.aspx) that runs for 5-10 sec:

```
<%
For i = 0 To 500000
  response.write(".<br>")
Next
%>
```

The preloader.htm is just some simple html but it is never shown.

Can anyone see what is missing? Thank you :-)